# Trying to list the 1st and second column but all text are indexed as one

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

Im trying to put into list two seperate column from an input file but they are all indexed the same how do i fix this.

```
name = []
income = []

with open('region-income.dat') as f:
    parse = f.readlines()[8:]
    for x in parse:
       name.append(x.split(' ')[0])
    print (name)
```

this code produces this outcome
[image]

from this input file
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it ?

```py
name = []
income = []

with open('region-income.dat') as f:
    parse = f.readlines()[8:]
    for x in parse:
       row = x.split()
       name.append(row[0])
       income.append(row[1])

print(name)
print(income)
```

It seems the XIII line is separated with tabs (`\t`) instead of spaces so I recommend just using `split()` which will split on all space-like characters.

Then the second column should just correspond to the second value of `x.split()` (stored into `row`) so we access it with `row[1]`.

Comment: @noobiecoder no worries. And whenever an answer fixes your problem you should mark it as validated, that's how stackoverflow knows the question is resolved.

Comment: how do i do that? im new here